# Wrong order in string array

Tags: arrays, swift, delegates, segue

I have this code that passes the entries from textfield and adds them to a string array in another view controller. The problem is, the order is not correct.

This is my code:

```
 //Textfields
 @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var text4: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var text5: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var text6: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Delegates each textfield
    text1.delegate = self
    text2.delegate = self
    text3.delegate = self
    text4.delegate = self
    text5.delegate = self
    text6.delegate = self

    //Tags each textfield
    text1.tag = 1
    text2.tag = 2
    text3.tag = 3
    text4.tag = 4
    text5.tag = 5
    text6.tag = 6

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    let nextTag: NSInteger = textField.tag + 1;

    if let nextResponder: UIResponder! = textField.superview!.viewWithTag(nextTag){
        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()

    }

    else {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    return false

}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! secondView

    if segue.identifier == segueID {

        //Adds the textfield entries to the string array on the second view controller
        destination.stringArray = view.subviews.flatMap { ($0 as? UITextField)?.text }

        destination.delegate = self

    }

}
```

But I have no idea what is wrong with my code, why would it send the incorrect order to my array. My array looks like this:

["q", "w", "e", "t", "y", "r"]

when it should be...

["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"]

This is just random letters I chose, the entries could be anything really. But the order is important. Could someone check my code, see where did I go wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort the `UITextField(s)` you are retrieving

So replace this

```
destination.stringArray = view.subviews.flatMap { ($0 as? UITextField)?.text }
```

with this

```
destination.stringArray = view
    .subviews
    .flatMap { $0 as? UITextField }
    .sort { $0.0.tag < $0.1.tag }
    .flatMap { $0.text }
```

Comment: This actually worked. I had to sort them out, of course. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, go from the tag to the field instead of the field to the tag:

```
destination.stringArray = (1...6).flatMap({ (view.viewWithTag($0) as? UITextField).text})
```